# How to set the environment default python in anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, pytorch

It makes me crazy, In anaconda I create the environment with the defualt iterpreter python3.4   Next I install pytorch 0.4.1

```
conda install pytorch=0.4.1 cuda80 -c pytorch
```

After this I found that the pytorch was installed in python3.6!

And the environment defualt interpreter is chaged from python3.4 to python3.6.

I am very confused what happend ? How shoud I fix it back? change defualt python back to python3.4? Hope some one could help me.

The commands I typed in are as follows:

```
conda create -n pointgen python=3.4 ipykernel
source activate pointgen
conda install pytorch=0.4.1 cuda80 -c pytorch
```

Thats all. What Novak said is right, there is remaining question is how could I manually change the python version from 3.6 back to 3.4, is there any config file I can deal with?

Comment: Please show the entire sequence of commands you ran, from creating the py 3.4 env, to installing pytorch, to checking the Python version.

Comment: It's impossible to say what your mistake was otherwise.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Hi I updated the question ,thank you for your reminding

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [here](https://pytorch.org/) there is no version of pytorch for python3.4... The default version of pytorch is for python3.6 and that is the version you installed installed. In the process anaconda prompts you that it will have to upgrade/downgrade some package versions and there is probably the the line in which it says it will upgrade python to 3.6

Comment: It is really helpful , thanks so much!   then how could I manually change the python back to version 3.4?

Comment: I don't think you can. If you manually change the python version, you will break the pytorch package and then the environment is useless. What you can do is create a new environment with python 3.4, and find the previous version of pytorch that is working with python 3.4 (if exists) and try to install it with pip from inside of the environment. I hope this will work for you :)

Comment: You can find the versions [here](https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/) on official PyTorch website

Comment: thank you！ you really help solve all of my problem ,thank you so much !!

Comment: It said that "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." So sorry ,I will try to vote it ,give me some time